# How to add Java Library inside Oracle EBS r11 in order to use Java script in SQL

Tags: java, oracle-ebs

I have a java script and want to use it in SQL oracle but don't know how and where to add the 3rd java library in the server.

I found one folder name `lib`

Is it the right folder or there is another folder I can Idd? which I have the .jar file need to add

I wrote a java code to sign a file from `Starkbank` library and in order to be able to us the java code I have to add `starkbank` library java file

```
import com.starkbank.ellipticcurve.PrivateKey;
import com.starkbank.ellipticcurve.PublicKey;
import com.starkbank.ellipticcurve.Signature;
import com.starkbank.ellipticcurve.Ecdsa;
import com.starkbank.ellipticcurve.Ecdsa;
import com.starkbank.ellipticcurve.PublicKey;
import com.starkbank.ellipticcurve.Signature;
import com.starkbank.ellipticcurve.utils.ByteString;
import com.starkbank.ellipticcurve.utils.File;
import java.util.*;

public class NewClass3{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        // Read files
       // String publicKeyPem = File.read("publicKey.pem");
        
        String PrivKeyPem = File.read("ec-secp256k1-priv-key.pem");



      //  PublicKey publicKey = PublicKey.fromPem(publicKeyPem);
       
        PrivateKey privateKey = PrivateKey.fromPem(PrivKeyPem);
        
          
    Base64.Encoder enc = Base64.getEncoder();
        Base64.Decoder dec = Base64.getDecoder();
        
    String str = "LcHeQ9b2bhNW291aOgeXhBHKa1uHmNoKf/ATfX+AJbo=";
  



        // Decode data
        String decoded = new String(dec.decode(str));
        System.out.println("decoded value is \t" + decoded);
        System.out.println("original value is \t" + str);
        


        // Generate Signature
        Signature signature = Ecdsa.sign(decoded, privateKey);

        // Return the signature verification status
        System.out.println("signature: " + signature);

         // Encode into Base64 format - This value should add in QR code

        String base64 = signature.toBase64();
 
        // print encoded String
        System.out.println("Encoded String:\n" + base64);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not [delete a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74139304/1509264) and then post the same question again. [Edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74139304/edit) to improve it and ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: The title talks about Oracle EBS but the question talks about SQL and it is unclear where you want to use this Java library and what you want to do with it. If you want to add a Jar file to an Java-enabled Oracle RDBMS then use the `loadjava` utility; **NEVER** play with the file structures and try to include it manually through the file system.

Comment: @MT0 I edited my post which I mentioned why I need it and what is the java code for, many thanks for your reply, and please how can I use `loadjava` ?

Comment: "I have a java script" Please [edit] the question and include the Java script. "and want to use it in SQL oracle" Please [edit] the question and include details of how you want to use it. It is impossible to tell you how to use something when we don't know what it is or how you want to use it.

Comment: You still have not told us how you want to use it in Oracle (whether that is EBS or RDBMS is still unclear). Additionally, your Java method returns `void` (i.e. it does not return anything) so using it elsewhere is going to be almost impossible.

Comment: @MT0 actually I am fresh on oracle sql, but want to sign the `str` which will come from db and send the output `base64` to store it in db.